# Problems calling Cufon.Replace from within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cufon

I'm doing a content loader and the content that gets loaded needs some Cufon action. 
And that doesn't work right now since I only apply Cufon when the initial page loads. And not the newly loaded content.

Now, shouldn't this be working?

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
     Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4, .menuwrapper', { fontFamily: 'advent'});}
```

Or am I not getting something?
I've also tried calling Cufon.Replace right after the procedure that calls the loadContent function, but that only applies the Cufon the next time I click a link.

```
 $('.dynload').live('click', function(){
 var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
 $('#content').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
 $('#ajaxloader').fadeIn('normal');
 window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length);
 Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4, .menuwrapper', { fontFamily: 'advent'});
```

How can I make sure Cufon is applied as soon as possible after loading new content? I was thinking about calling Cufon.replace the moment before the new content is faded in. But this doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

The `load` function probably is asynchronous, so the content won't be there yet when you run the Cufon command. Did you try adding the cufon replace at the end of the `showNewContent()` function? (I'm assuming that will be called when the content has been loaded)

BTW: if you already use cufon on page-load you could/should use `Cufon.refresh()` to re-apply the replace instead of doing a new replace.

Comment: Yes, I've tried putting it at the end of every function. And the same thing happens, nothing. Pretty strange isn't it?